# Does jquery support beforeBlur / afterBlur events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<input type="radio" />`, and a `<select>` following it, and I want show/hide this select element when the radio button is selected or unselected.

When I bind to the `blur` event, `jQuery(this).is(':checked')` says that the radio is still checked. (By the way is this browser specific behaviour?)

So is there a `beforeBlur`/`afterBlur`, `click`, `focus`, etc... function or hack I can use to capture the selected state of the radio input?

One idea is to set a timeout for the function that will change the visibility of the select element.

----EDIT----

so here the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/jHbwK/1/

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="radio">
<span style="display: none;">text1</span>
<br />
<input type="radio" value="2" name="radio">
<span style="display: none;">text2</span>
```

and

```
$('input[name="radio"]').change(function(){
    reset();
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).next().css('display','');
    else
        $(this).next().css('display','none');
});
function reset(){
    $('input[name="radio"]').next('span').css('display','none');
}
```

so when any event is fired up the item is still checked, and i want to know is there a way to make second part of "if" to work -

```
else
    $(this).next().css('display','none');
```

it never runs

So, is it a browser-specific behaviour, or i can use something like "beforeBlur" and "afterBlur" events in javascript?

----EDIT----

Analogue of what i want is before and after triggers in RDBMS. Seems javascript only has a "before" trigger, am I right?

Comment: perhaps the 'change' event will be more of help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this OK for you?

HTML:

```
<ul id="boxes">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="box" value="1" checked>
        <span> SELECT 1 </span>     
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="box" value="2">
        <span> SELECT 2 </span>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#boxes input:radio').click(function() {
    $(this).next().show().closest('li').siblings().children('span').hide();
}).triggerHandler('click');
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fa9cK/

---

**Update:**

The focus and blur events do not occur when you click on radio-boxes, but only when you use the TAB key to focus trough the elements on the page. Therefore, these events are not of use to you.

Next, the change and click event do occur when you click on radio-boxes, but only on the radio-box that was clicked. So, if one radio-box is checked, and you click on another radio-box, then the change event will occur only on the radio-box that was clicked, but not on the one that lost its checked state. That makes the change event also useless for you.

Therefore, use the click event.

See this demo to understand what event types are triggered: http://jsfiddle.net/BWvWW/

Note that inside the click handler, the radio-box will always report that it is checked. So your strategy has to be this:

When the user clicks on a radio-box, 1. display the corresponding SELECT element, and then, 2. find all other radio-boxes from that same radio-box-list and hide all corresponding SELECT elements. Note that this is exactly what my original demo does.

Comment: This is not that answer that i ideally want to hear, but yes, this looks better. Maybe you also can give me a link about core javascript or browser behavior somewhere in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript that explains why change events fired up beforeChange of items?

Comment: thanks, very helpful. now i understand why i was "fixing" not so long ago this behavior of radio buttons and form submitting with $('radio').click(function(){$(this).focus();})

Answer (score 2):

As Ken Egozi pointed out, 'Change' would be the best approach i think:

http://api.jquery.com/change/